# Get scale and rotation angle from CGAffineTransform?

Tags: ios, animation, rotation, scale, transformation

I want to get *scale* factor and *rotation* angle form view. I've already applied `CGAffineTransform` to that view.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The current transformation of an `UIView` is stored in its `transform` property. This is a `CGAffineTransform` structure, you can read more about that here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html

You can get the angle in radians from the transform like this:

```
CGFloat angle = atan2f(yourView.transform.b, yourView.transform.a);
```

If you want the angle in degrees you need to convert it like this:

```
angle = angle * (180 / M_PI);
```

Get the scale like this:

```
CGFloat scaleX = view.transform.a;
CGFloat scaleY = view.transform.d;
```

Comment: I wonder why the CGAffineTransform class doesn't have properties for this kind of stuff?

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem, found this solution, but it only partially solved my problem.
In fact the proposed solution for extracting the scale from the transform:

*(all code in swift)*

```
scaleX = view.transform.a
scaleY = view.transform.d
```

only works when the rotation is `0`.

When the rotation is not `0` the `transform.a` and `transform.d` are influenced by the rotation. To get the proper values you can use

```
scaleX = sqrt(pow(transform.a, 2) + pow(transform.c, 2))
scaleY = sqrt(pow(transform.b, 2) + pow(transform.d, 2))
```

**note** that the result is always positive. If you are also interested in the sign of the scaling (the view is flipped), then the sign of the scaling is the sign of `transform.a` for x flip and `transform.d` for y flip. One way to inherit the sign.

```
scaleX = (transform.a/abs(transform.a)) * sqrt(pow(transform.a, 2) + pow(transform.c, 2))
scaleY = (transform.d/abs(transform.d)) * sqrt(pow(transform.b, 2) + pow(transform.d, 2))
```

Answer (score 5):

In Swift 3:

`let rotation = atan2(view.transform.b, view.transform.a)`

Comment: You don't need to convert the argument types — the standard library provides overloads for `atan2` that take `CGFloat`, `Double`, or `Float`.

Comment: I get an error: "Cannot convert value of type 'CGFloat' to expected argument type 'Float'"

Comment: ```let rotation = atan2(view.transform.b, view.transform.a)``` works!